# Какой язык программирования стоит изучать новичку для создания игр для Android, iOS

Tags: разработка-игр

Какой язык программирования стоит изучать новичку для создания игр для Android, iOS

Comment: язык Java, но еще больше учить алгоритмы

Comment: Java только для Андроид. Для IOS не подойдет

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько вариантов и все хороши:

1. Java если писать через Андроид студию - для Андроид телефонов
2. C# если писать на Андроид и IOS (Нужен МАС для компиляции + лицензия) среда разработки Xamarin - для Андроид и IOS
3. Objective-C или Swift под IOS на МАС оборудовании + лицензия - для IOS

P.S. Лицензия на МАС стоит 100$

Comment: Откуда цифра $100? В эту сумму не входит стоимость лицензии на MacOS X?

Comment: "На вашем Apple ID (либо у одной из компаний, которая добавила ваш Apple ID в свою команду) должна быть активирована так называемая Apple Developer Program — оплачиваемая раз в год «подписка», дающая вам доступ к Apple Developer Center и возможность публиковать ваши приложения в App Store. На текущий момент стоимость в пересчете на год невелика и составляет в районе $99 за год пользования." Подробнее можешь ознакомиться тут https://habr.com/ru/post/280626/